# Running Hologram cellular network from startup issues [cannot run on rc.local or .bashrc]

Tags: networking, terminal, raspberry-pi-desktop, systemd-startup

I’m playing around with the hologram Nova cellular USB kit and I’m trying to create an automatic connection using the /etc/rc.local file. Hologram uses it's own way of connecting to a ppp0 network connection and the way to enable or start a connection is through:

```
sudo hologram network connect
```

This command runs on the command line without any problem. However it doesn’t seem to ever run on boot up.

For those of you who aren’t familiar with the Nova Hologram you can follow [this](https://hologram.io/) link

In order to get a ppp0 connection.

So I have tried a rc.local edit just simply adding the command and it just doesn't seem to run... I have also tried running a crontab command (same command after reboot) in order to run. However it just doesn’t seem to run at all...

After running crontab under admin priviledges:

```
(sudo crontab e-)
```

I type at the end of the file:

```
@reboot sudo hologram network connect
```

Nothing seems to happen when I reboot or power on Raspberry pi.

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you kindly

Edit: After creating the unit service for systemd, as suggested by @Ingo Here is the following log result:

```
Ok Here's the output from the termination error:

pi@BerryPi2:~ $ sudo systemctl status holConn.service
● holConn.service - Hologram Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/holConn.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2019-07-05 00:41:26 EDT; 14s ago
  Process: 1249 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/hologram network connect 
(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1249 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 05 00:41:20 BerryPi2 pppd[1256]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyACM0
Jul 05 00:41:24 BerryPi2 pppd[1256]: local  IP address xx.xx.x.x        # -> note I masked the real IP and DNS addresses
Jul 05 00:41:24 BerryPi2 pppd[1256]: remote IP address xx.xx.x.x
Jul 05 00:41:24 BerryPi2 pppd[1256]: primary   DNS address xx.xx.xxx.xxx
Jul 05 00:41:24 BerryPi2 pppd[1256]: secondary DNS address xx.xx.xxx.xxx
Jul 05 00:41:26 BerryPi2 hologram[1249]: PPP session started
Jul 05 00:41:26 BerryPi2 pppd[1256]: Terminating on signal 15
Jul 05 00:41:26 BerryPi2 pppd[1256]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Jul 05 00:41:26 BerryPi2 pppd[1256]: Sent 0 bytes, received 0 bytes.
Jul 05 00:41:26 BerryPi2 pppd[1256]: Connection terminated.
```

2nd Edit:

After the updates to the unit file, including the oneshot and other options suggested by @Ingo, the service stays active but shows status as exited.

```
pi@BerryPi2:~ $ sudo systemctl status holConn.service
● holConn.service - Hologram Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/holConn.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2019-07-05 11:55:42 EDT; 2min 19s ago
  Process: 507 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/hologram network connect 
(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 507 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/holConn.service

Jul 05 11:55:39 BerryPi2 systemd[1]: Starting Hologram Service...
Jul 05 11:55:42 BerryPi2 sudo[624]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/modprobe option
Jul 05 11:55:42 BerryPi2 sudo[624]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 05 11:55:42 BerryPi2 sudo[624]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 05 11:55:42 BerryPi2 hologram[507]: ERROR: Modem not detected
Jul 05 11:55:42 BerryPi2 systemd[1]: Started Hologram Service.
```

I'm guessing we have to modify the After option to wait for both network and usb modem to be recognized? is there such an option? I tried putting the idle.target because I read it was basically when the Pi is ready and everything has loaded... but I'm most likely wrong.

Comment: As far as I understand there is an external device called **Nova**. On the RasPi you use a program named `hologram` to connect to `Nova` by **ppp**. Can you confirm this?

Comment: yeah, the external device is a 3G usb device and its managed by hologram.io more info can be found at that website (https://hologram.io/)

Comment: You can edit your question. Please add this information to it.

Comment: @Ingo, I thought it was all in there, but I have reworded the question, hopefully this is a bit more clear? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Instead you should use a *systemd* Unit file to start your service. With *systemd* you have many options to make your service run. Your command only runs one time and does not stay in the background as a service. So we have to use `oneshot`. We have to find the condition that is available on the command line but not early on boot up. First we can try to wait until `network-online.target`. If it doesn't help we can try to start the command again after a time until it is started. This provides that the command fails without connection but it seems it finishes with `(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`, why? The best is when we know what other service (condition available on command line) is needed so we can start our command `After` that without only fixing symptoms.

Try this unit file. The possible alternatives I have commented out. You can create the unit with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --full --force edit holConn.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Connect Hologram service
After=network-online.target
# After=service needed to be available

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
# Restart=on-failure
# RestartSec=5
# TimeoutStartSec=30
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/hologram network connect

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You can edit it again with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --full edit holConn.service
```

Enable the new service:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable holConn.service
```

and reboot. Check status with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status holConn.service
```

It is likely that it doesn't run on the first attempt due to missing conditions. We will look at it then.

**Update:**
Using the chat we have found that there is an additional condition. A ppp connection on interface **ppp0** must be established before starting the service. That was the missing `# After=service needed to be available`. We can check with `sys-subsystem-net-devices-ppp0.device` if the interface is up. So the final Unit file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Connect Hologram Service
After=network-online.target
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-ppp0.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/hologram network connect

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I’m not very well versed on systemd Unit files, but I can definitely elaborate on my question if you need any more information! Thank you again!

Comment: @Agustin I have updated the answer.

Comment: It seems we're in sync, because I found some documentation on doing this, however while the service ran on boot, the log shows it disconnects almost immediately... and if I run the same command on the terminal as myself it runs without a problem... :(

Comment: Ok, I have updated the question with the log after running the service, thank you!

Comment: @Agustin I have updated the answer. Please give me feedback.

Comment: shoot so close, ran it and was activated and stayed active... powered off the pi, powered back on, and well... the question has been updated with the status, basically it says active (exited)

Comment: I think it's the case that even after network-online.target is active, tty or serial communications hasn't activated yet (since the modem isn't found at that point in time.) I would have to guess that if we can modify the After option for when the OS has fully loaded including serial communications? I'm going through the man systemd pages to see if I find such option... (also googling a lot lol).

After running sudo systemctl restart holConn.service manually right after I log in via ssh, the service starts successfully...

Comment: @Agustin Looks better, it's a step forward. Just to verify that it's only a timing problem add this statement to the [Service] section: `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5`. You may increase the seconds step by step. But this should not be the final solution because it delays the whole service start. When the command line execution works then look with `systemctl` if you find something like `sys-subsystem-net-devices-ppp0.device` or similar. If it is there then try in the unit file `After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-ppp0.device` (or similar).

Comment: @Agustin With *Starting Hologram Service...* there is a `sudo` running. This is not clean because systemd start its services with root rights by default. Because there is a *Hologram Service* starting it may be possible that there is already a systemd service for it. This could be an important information. Look for all available services with `systemctl list-unit-files`.

Comment: I'm sorry, how would I use systemctl to find sys-subsystem-net-devices-ppp0.device? I ran the log after connecting and this time it failed to start the service.. but I don't see anything referenced to sys-subsystem.... edit: ah, got your message a bit later... okay looking for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95786/discussion-between-ingo-and-agustin).