# Created a Raspberry Pi 3B+ Wireless Hotspot, how can I extend the hotspot via Ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp, hotspot, raspbian-lite

I have successfully created a WiFi hotspot for my RPi 3B+ using a Hologram Nova and the embedded WiFi card on the Pi. However I realized that the ethernet interface has disappeared and cannot extend the hotspot to the Ethernet interface.

My setup is a mix of tutorials on how to create a hotspot but the main gist can be found [here](https://howtoraspberrypi.com/create-a-wi-fi-hotspot-in-less-than-10-minutes-with-pi-raspberry/). I only changed the interface to be taken as the source the ppp0 instead of eth0.

Now I find myself needing to use the ethernet interface to plug a device that has no WiFi capabilities but does have the ethernet interface.

So my question is, how can I modify my hotspot to allow the dhcp server to serve the ethernet interface as well? I would like it to be dynamic as well so that I could potentially add an ethernet switch for more local devices.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

As per your request, I ran:

```
ip --brief link show
```

[image: result]

And when I run

```
ifconfig
```

I get lo, ppp0 and wlan0 but no eth0.

Here is a screenshot of my current /etc/network/interfaces file

[image: network/interfaces]

Comment: "My setup is a mix of tutorials" - so how are we to know what you did!

Comment: What does it mean: "*I realized that the ethernet interface has disappeared*"? Do you find **eth0** with `ip --brief link show`? What  does it mean: "*the interface to be taken as the source the ppp0 instead of eth0*"? A source of what? Do you mean **ppp0** is taken as an uplink to the internet router/modem/connection?

Comment: @Milliways, I did mentioned the only thing I did was that I changed the interface to be taken as the source ppp0 instead of eth0

Comment: @Ingo, hello again, The interface doesn't show up when I do "ipconfig", please see the screenshot I have added on the question.

Comment: @Ingo, edit: "ifconfig" instead of ipconfig

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question. So I do not have to type enxb827eb3f0e89 and can copy and paste it. Have I typed the right number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your installation you have [predictable network interface names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) enabled so you will not always find classical interface names like **eth0**. Your wired interface has the name **enxb827eb3f0e89**. Instead of **eth0** you have to use this name.

If you don't like predictable network interface names you can use `sudo raspi-config` to disable it with "*2 Network Options -> N3 Network interface names*". If it doesn't help you can edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` and add `net.ifnames=0` to the line.

You can use the wired interface name (whatever name do you use) to configure either a routed or bridged interface. I suggest to use a *bridge* together with the **wlan0** interface so all devices on wifi and wired are on the same subnet. I do not use deprecated `ifupdown`, managed with `/etc/network/interfaces`, since years so I cannot help much with this setup to create a bridge. I use *systemd-networkd* and do it this way: [How can I set my pi 3 up to be WiFi AND ethernet router simultaneously?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/99598/79866). In that setup I think you could just replace **usb0** with **ppp0**.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I will check this when I get back from work. Will keep you posted

Comment: Okay, I have disabled predictable network interfaces names, I will go through your tutorial as well, however when I disabled the predictable network names, the auto boot from this post broke: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100200/running-hologram-cellular-network-from-startup-issues-cannot-run-on-rc-local-or/100211#100211... will add a timer for now see if that for now fixes it.

Comment: @Agustin or just use enxb827eb3f0e89 instead of eth0.

Comment: well i thought about that, but then wouldn't the correct way be to not use predictable network interface names? haha

Comment: @Agustin It's your decision what to use. It's nothing wrong with predictable names but I don't like  this unmentionable names. If you switch you have to "repair" all other setups using an interface name. I always start my raspis from beginning with the option in cmdline.txt so I do not have a mix up.

Comment: That's awesome, so I've been going through your tutorials/posts and I can't really figure out which one is for me https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way/88234#88234 because I am using a ppp0 device as the internet provider... and want to use ethernet and wlan to spread the internet from ppp0

Comment: @Agustin You will not find the setup for you in the link you have posted. Please read the last paragraph of my answer and use the link there. As far as I understood that's what you want.

Comment: Amazing.. just amazing. This is exactly what I needed! One small change I made was instead of using usb0 I changed it for ppp0 when masquerading and it works perfectly. Side question just in case you know about it... would I be able to install Open VPN on the Pi and have it all launch so that I can connect to the Raspberry pi outside of the local network?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96080/discussion-between-ingo-and-agustin).